# Magento 2 : add google map in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs, knockout

I want to add google map in Magento 2 checkout page.

Added API url and key to phtml using below code

```
<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Test\Vendor\Block\Map"
                   name="google.map"
                   as="googleapi"
                   template="Test_CVendor::map.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
```

And added my script to map.phtml.

```
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places<?php echo $this->getApiKey(); ?>">
</script>
```

I have added custom component in `checkout_index_index.xml`
from that component I have set template and define div over their like

Now I want to render google map to this div.

Can any one please guide me for which binding I need to use and how to render map over this div.